# Из текстового файла в SQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, java, синтаксический-анализ

Хочу создать базу данных слов. Есть текстовый файл, где я храню слова таким образом:

```
"...
stop стоп
car машина
cat кот ..."
```

И мне нужно записать это в базу данных mySQL. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом или кодом, как мне записать из файла в бд в таблицу, где будет столбцы "перевод" и "слово". Также прошу отсылки, где можно максимально "на пальцах" прочитать про jdbc, связь проекта с MySQL и, по возможности, без воды и внедрения в глубь.

Comment: А таких готовых баз нет?

Comment: @maotm, возможно, есть, но я долго это дело гуглил и не нашел, увы, ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведи строки в своем текстовом файле к виду

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2)
     VALUES (value1_1, value1_2),(value2_1, value2_2);
```

А затем выполни SQL-запрос.

Про JDBС и прочие технологии без воды и внедрения вглубь рассказывают сотрудники компаний, которых заказчики нанимают за деньги для выполнения проекта. Нет желания нанимать кого-то - научись фильтровать полезную информацию из Интернета.

**Обновление**

Replace в редакторе помогает. Заменяем символ переноса строки на

```
"),("
```

Пробел на

```
","
```

Добавляем ")" в конце файла. После этого в первой строчке в начале пишем

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES (
```

Запрос готов, все строки добавятся.

Comment: @Get JDBS?

Comment: JDBC, опечатка случилась.

Comment: Как я понимаю, у него таких записей вагон и маленькая тележка. Не будет же он приводить все записи в рекомендуемый Вами вид.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Ну тоже вариант, конечно. Но есть стандартная утилита импорта.

Comment: Когда нет времени изучить что-то, на помощь приходят простые решения. ))

Comment: @Get увы и ах,там изучать толком нечего.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже была нужда. Элементарный поиск в Интернет выдает [результат](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/mysqlimport.html).